# How to select from a DATETIME column using only a date?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

I have a DATETIME column on my table which stores when a record was created. I want to select only the records created on a particular date. If I try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE postedOn =  '2012-06-06'
```

It returns no rows even though there are many rows in the table with the `postedOn` set as 
`2012-06-06 21:42:02`, `2012-06-06 07:55:17` , and so forth.

Any ideas?

Comment: The reason why your original code won't work is because there are no dates that equal exactly '2012-06-06 00:00:00', using Date(), as others suggested, on the values will remove the time info and make the comparison return results.

Comment: You can always truncate the time off a `datetime` with this trick: `CAST(FLOOR(CAST(some_datetime AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)` - one of my favorites.  Comes in handy for reporting for day roll-ups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) scalar:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE date(postedOn) =  '2012-06-06'
```

Comment: Is that likely to make the queries slow if there are a lot of records?

Comment: No. The alternative is worse: keeping two fields, one for date and one for time.

Comment: @tony Worse in terms of maintainance, but what about performance?

Comment: @ClickUpvote:  You can check it with EXPLAIN.  I just ran it, and it says that it will use the index (which is to be expected).  So the optimization should be fine.

Comment: @MarkWilkins What if there's no index on this column?

Comment: You wont find any system that has fields for date and time, they all use datetime, so it must be fast enough. Besides, most languages like PHP have a built in support for DateTime - as if it is a primitive type, so it cannot go faster than that.

Comment: @ClickUpvote:  Without an index, then it will likely be slow (assuming a large table)... but the use of the scalar function probably would not have any affect.

Comment: I believe DATE() is reading just a segment of the DateTime string, so IMO it would be as fast as reading from different fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE DATE(postedOn) = '2012-06-06'
```

DATE() returns the date part of a datetime field.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Answer (score 1):

Create a time range by adding a day to the date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE postedOn >= '2012-06-06' and postedOn < '2012-06-07'
```

This is the most efficient way, as the query can use an index on the field.

Comment: Would have to do a second query for this to do `SELECT DATE_ADD($oldDate, interval 1 day)` or the equivalent of that in calculating the next day's date, so the benefits of this seem neutralized compared to using `date()`

Comment: @ClickUpvote: Calculating the next date is only done once, and then the values can be directly compared to the index. Using date() means that it has to use a table scan to calculate the date value for every value in the table.