# C# get appointment from database based on DateTime value and id

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, nullreferenceexception

I have a monthcalendar on my WinForm. When a user clicks a date I want to check if an appointment exist for that user on the day he clicked and then display some information. I check this information in a MySql database using the MySql connector. I currently check in the table Gebruiker_has_Afspraak for an Appointment id corresponding with the user ID then in the Afspraak table I check for the same Date as the date clicked on the Monthcalendar. If it is the same it will return the location of the appointment(More info in the future).

I have this code :

```
 public List<string> checkAfspraakDate(DateTime datum, string type, string id)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        List<string> result1 = new List<string>();
        if (this.openConnection() == true)
        {
            //Afspraak_id ophalen uit Gebruiker_has_afspraak
            string query = "SELECT Afspraak_id FROM Gebruiker_has_Afspraak WHERE Gebruiker_id = '" + id + "' ";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
              }

              reader.Close();
            }
            cmd.Cancel();
            //Afspraak gegevens uit table halen | Gebaseerd op Afspraak_id^ en datum_today
            foreach (string item in result)
            {
                query = "SELECT afspraak_locatie FROM Afspraak WHERE id = '" + item + "' AND datum = '" + datum +"'";
                MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader1.Read())
                    {
                        result1.Add(reader1.GetString(0));
                    }

                    reader1.Close();
                }
                cmd1.Cancel();
            }
            return result1;

        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
```

The first code will extract the 'Afspraak_id' from the table 'Gebruiker_has_Afspraak' if the current user id matches the user id in the table.

Then the 'Afspraak_id' will be used to check for appointments in the 'Afspraak' table where the Date == the clicked day on the month calendar.

I am currently trying to compare a DateTime object to the date in the database, because the date in the database is stored as a datetime value. 
I also tried it with a string but that did not work either. I get a system.NullReferenceException on the 'while(reader1.Read())' part. I think it is because i get a null from the database but that is not right because almost all dates have appointments.

Comment: Don't concantenate strings to create a query, you're vulnerable to SQL-injection this way.

Comment: The id and date are not filled in by the user but are based on clicks so injection is not a problem here.

Comment: I'd still use parameters instead of concatenation. If only for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are concatenating a C# DateTime object with a string that will result in the default `.ToString()` being called on the object. This is dependent on the culture of the pc/server it is running on for the format in which it is returned.

Since MySQL has the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` this will probably be different and thus not result in a match. You'll need to call `datum.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`.

Keep in mind that your check will also check if the date up to the seconds match, you'll probably want to check only the date part.

Comment: I just found that out indeed, My format in the database is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss but my datum variable has dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss I can parse them or to string in the correct order. But i want to check for the whole day so if i check on the day part will my database accept that if i leave out the hours minutes and seconds?

Comment: Example i check for yyyy-MM-dd but the database has yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss will the query work or not?

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923264/how-to-select-from-a-datetime-column-using-only-a-date) answer that part. You have to convert your mysql datetime to date for it to ignore the time part

Comment: but i still need to have the time to display my appointment correctly- Shall i do this with an extra field?

Comment: Oh never mind, I can just select the date and based on date()